# Android - Putting 4 images in a grid of 2x2

Tags: android

I have 4 images in my XML and I would like to display them in a grid of 2x2 in my RelativeLayout and I want the ones in the same line to occupy the width equally. I tried to use `wrap_content` but it didn't work, the images are not showing and I want to avoid setting a fixed width/height (like my code below) because of differences in screen sizes.

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture2"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture3"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_below="@id/picture"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture4"
                android:layout_height="140dp"
                android:layout_width="140dp"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture3"
                android:layout_below="@id/picture2"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to do this by using two LinearLayouts:

```
<RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:focusable="false">
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnLL"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture2"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            <LinearLayout
                android:id="@+id/btnLL1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_below="@id/btnLL">
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture3"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_below="@id/picture"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
                android:id="@+id/picture4"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:layout_toRightOf="@id/picture3"
                android:layout_below="@id/picture2"
                fresco:viewAspectRatio="1"
                fresco:fadeDuration="300"
                fresco:actualImageScaleType="focusCrop"
                fresco:failureImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:placeholderImage="@android:color/transparent"
                fresco:progressBarAutoRotateInterval="1000"
                fresco:progressBarImage="@drawable/loading_circle"
                fresco:progressBarImageScaleType="centerInside"/>
            </LinearLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the relativelayout itself becomes unnecessary in this though, you could just do it with only linearlayouts.

if you want to use relativelayout, then you could add an empty View in the middle of the relativelayout(centered) and place the other views in relation to that.

another method would be to utilize PercentRelativeLayout but it was added only in 23 and deprecated in 26! https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentRelativeLayout.html